# Masking problems in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mask

I have a group of paths and a rectangle like so:

[image: image with group of paths and a rectangle]

I am trying to cut a hole in the rectangle using the group of paths, I have managed to do this in Photoshop just fine but I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to illustrator. Something like this:

[image: result from photoshop]

Any help would be appreciated, step by step instructions would be even better!

Comment: Welcome to the community. Questions that are easily answered from reviewing documentation or a web search for an appropriate tutorial are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "cutting a hole" I assume you mean that you actually want to edit the path of the dark gray rectangle in back?

Select all.

Window→Pathfinder→Divide. Used to be called "Mix Hard" in older versions.

Use the white arrow to select your large gray box, and it should have the correct holes punched in it.